# How to break a loop after specific duration of time in dart?

Tags: dart

I was trying to break the loop after 5 seconds so I used Timer class of dart. But in every loop state timer.tick value is 1. I need help how can I break the loop after 5s or any specific duration of time?

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'dart:io';

main(List<String> args) {
  String usrName;
  Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
    while (true) {
      print("What's you're name?");
      usrName = stdin.readLineSync() as String;
      print("Welcome $usrName.");
      //print("${timer.tick}s passed");
      if (timer.tick == 5) {
        print("Ended");
        timer.cancel();
        break;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Take a look at `Stopwatch`: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.1/dart-core/Stopwatch-class.html

Comment: can you give me the code? how can I use Stopwatch to do this task?

Comment: Can you provide more details of what you want your program to do? Should it just wait for an answer but if the answer comes after 5 seconds, the program should stop? `readLineSync` will halt your program until an answer has been given so I just want to make sure that is what you want.

Comment: I was trying to build a quiz app that will ask the user some questions and when time is up it will automatically stop asking questions and show the result.

Comment: Ah ok, that is something different. I will try think about how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

A *synchronous* loop in Dart does not allow any other events to run, including the timer events which would increment the tick.

Either make your loop asynchronous (by doing `await` inside it in at least one place, and if you want a timer to run, do it with a `Future.delayed(Duartion.zero)` to ensure that it allows *timer* events to run, not just microtask.

Or, what I'd do if I actually want the loop to be synchronous, is to use a `Stopwatch`:

```dart
var sw = Stopwatch()..start();
while (sw.elapsedMilliseconds < 5000) {
  // keep doing
}
// done.
```

That will stop the loop. It won't time-out the request for input, and it won't allow anything else to run while waiting for input.
For those reasons, you might want to use something like what @jamesdlin has suggested.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things wrong with your current approach.  You've created a `Timer` that will create a *new* loop every second, but you instead want a single loop with a `Timer` that can break out of it.  Also, you unfortunately won't be able to use `stdin.readLineSync()` since that will block execution until the user enters an input line.  You will need a completely different approach.

`Future`s and `Stream`s have a `.timeout` method that can throw a `TimeoutException` (or return/emit a specified value). [`stdin`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-io/Stdin-class.html) unfortunately doesn't provide a direct way to read lines asynchronously, so you will need to use [`LineSplitter`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-convert/LineSplitter-class.html) on it manually.

Another complication is that `stdin` is a single-subscription stream, which makes reading individual lines a bit awkward.  We can use [`package:async`](https://pub.dev/packages/async)'s [`StreamQueue`](https://pub.dev/documentation/async/latest/async/StreamQueue-class.html) to make that more intuitive.

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:async/async.dart';

Future<void> main(List<String> args) async {
  final lines = StreamQueue<String>(utf8.decoder
      .bind(stdin)
      .transform(const LineSplitter())
      .timeout(const Duration(seconds: 5)));

  var questions = [
    'Question 1?',
    'Question 2?',
    'Question 3?',
  ];

  var answers = <String>[];

  for (var question in questions) {
    print(question);

    try {
      answers.add(await lines.next);
    } on TimeoutException {
      break;
    }

    print('');
  }
  lines.cancel();

  print('Got answers: $answers');
}
```